# Exporting an array from a promise, but not loading when required in another file?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, promise, javascript-objects, request-promise

I'm trying to make a request from a database and I need to combine the results of multiple columns into one array.
I've accomplished that by making all of the requests in Promise.all() and it works. 
However, the problem is that I need to access this data in a different file. When I require fileA in my fileB, the array appears to be empty?

fileA.js

```
const days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday"] 

function dbRequest(day){

    return knexInstance.select('shift_time',`${day}`).from('shr');
}

Promise.all([
            dbRequest(days[0] ? days[0]: null),
            dbRequest(days[1] ? days[1]: null),
            dbRequest(days[2] ? days[2]: null)
])
.then(results => {
    shiftR = results;
    console.log(shiftR)
    module.exports = { shiftR }; //the array only contains the dates once all the promises have been executed
});
```

FileB.js

```
const shiftR = require('./fileA');

console.log(shiftR);
```

I'm stumped on how to fix this. If there's a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do then I would appreciate the suggestions.

For context, this is what the database looks like, but I don't think this info is needed for the question.

```
shift_time  monday  tuesday  wednesday (...)
6 AM        1       1        1      
7 AM        2       2        2  
8 AM        3       3        3  
9 AM        3       3        3
```

Comment: You have to assign to `module.exports` synchronously.  As your code shows, you are assigning to `module.exports` in the `.then()` handler.  That is after your module has already returned and after the code that called `require()` has already retrieved the exports.  Thus, the exports are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the `Promise.all` *promise* to `module.exports`, so that you can call `.then` on the Promise in the other file:

```
// fileA.js
module.exports = Promise.all([
            dbRequest(days[0] ? days[0]: null),
            dbRequest(days[1] ? days[1]: null),
            dbRequest(days[2] ? days[2]: null)
])
.then(results => {
    return { shiftR: results };
});
```

```
// FileB.js

const shiftRProm = require('./fileA');
shiftRProm.then(({ shiftR }) => {
  console.log(shiftR);
});
```

If you're only trying to pass the resolved `shiftR` value to `FileB`, and nothing else, then there's no need to put the results into an object and destructure:

```
// fileA.js
module.exports = Promise.all([
            dbRequest(days[0] ? days[0]: null),
            dbRequest(days[1] ? days[1]: null),
            dbRequest(days[2] ? days[2]: null)
]);
```

```
// FileB.js

const shiftRProm = require('./fileA');
shiftRProm.then((shiftR) => {
  console.log(shiftR);
});
```

You can trim the code down by calling `.map` on the `days` array:

```
function dbRequest(day = null) {
  return knexInstance.select('shift_time', String(day)).from('shr');
}
module.exports = Promise.all(days.map(dbRequest));
```